# Choose filename of .msi installer when added to C:\Windows\Installer folder

Tags: windows-installer

I've created an .msi installer for a Windows application from Visual Studio and named the installer via the project properties box, e.g. MyApplication.msi, no problems there.

However, after installation, Windows saves the .msi folder to the installer cache at C:\Windows\Installer for uninstallation/reinstallation and renames it to something like 4363ab.msi (I understand this is to prevent file name clashes). Is there any way to prevent this from happening, so the .msi is saved as MyApplication.msi, other than manually renaming it?

I realize there is no real value in this, however my Client asks if it is possible, because they want what the .msi is to be clearly visible to any system admin without hovering over the .msi or reading the file properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible.  This is a private cached maintained by the windows installer service used for resilency and maintenance operations.  In previous versions of Windows it was "stripped" of embedded cabs leaving only the meta data as to consume less space.   This stripping invalidated the digital certificate and caused a problem starting in Windows Vista with UAC.   You would go to do an uninstall and it would say "publisher unverified".  That freaked people out so starting in Windows 7  MSFT started caching the full MSI there.

But that cache still isn't for us it's for MSI.  Now if the client is really interested in knowing what those MSIs are (or which one is there)  it would be trivial to create an MSICacheBrowser.exe  to use API calls to harvest all that information and display it to the user.

But you should never ever touch any of this.  Especially in production.